# Why does child have to import same modules parent did?

Tags: python, python-import

My main Python program (script to most) has elaborate import statements I'd rather not repeat in modules I import:

```
from __future__ import print_function       # Must be first import
from __future__ import with_statement       # Error handling for file opens

try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    import tkinter.font as font
    import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
    import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
    PYTHON_VER="3"
except ImportError: # Python 2
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
    import tkFont as font
    import tkFileDialog as filedialog
    import tkMessageBox as messagebox
    PYTHON_VER="2"
# print ("Python version: ", PYTHON_VER)

import subprocess32 as sp
import sys
import os
import time
import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import pickle
from random import shuffle
import getpass                      # Get user name for file storage

import locale                       # To set thousands separator as , or .
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') # Use '' for auto

# mserve modules
import location as lc               # Home grown module
```

As my program/script approaches 5,000 lines I've come over to the light side / (Dark side?) and started using imported modules of my own design. The first module is called `location.py` but!, lo and behold I've had to repeat import statements already imported in the parent program `mserve`.

EG at header:

```
from __future__ import print_function       # Must be first import
import getpass
import os
import pickle
import time
```

And just tonight on a new function I'm writing:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MsgDisplay:
    ''' Text Widget with status messages
    '''

    def __init__(self, title, toplevel, width, height):

        self.line_cnt = 0                   # Message lines displayed so far
        toplevel.update_idletasks()         # Get up-to-date window co-ords

        x = toplevel.winfo_x()
        y = toplevel.winfo_y()
        w = toplevel.winfo_width()
        h = toplevel.winfo_height()
        xd = (w/2) - (width/2)
        yd = (h/2) - (height/2)
        print('x:',x,'y:',y,'w:',w,'h:',h,
              'width:',width,'height:',height,'xd:',xd,'yd:',yd)
        
        ''' Mount message textbox window at centered in passed toplevel '''
        self.msg_top = tk.Toplevel()
        self.textbox = tk.Text(self.msg_top, height=height, width=width)
        self.msg_top.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d'%(width, height, x + xd, y + yd))
#        self.textbox.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
#        self.textbox.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.textbox.pack()
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")

    def Update(self, msg_list):
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
        time.sleep(.1)
        
    def Close(self):
        self.msg_top.destroy()
```

The new import I just added:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Is a shortcut / fudge because production version would need to be:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError: # Python 2
    import Tkinter as tk
```

Before preaching python 2.7.12 is obsolete please note I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 whose EOL is 2021. Also note we use Windows 2008 Server at work and legacy systems written in COBOL are common so who cares?

I must be doing something wrong because a module that is imported should not have to import what parent already did? In a normal environment the child should know / inherent what the parent already knows.

As an aside, tonight's new class "MsgDisplay" should be in parent and not in child. It was simpler to put the class in the child rather than figuring out how a child could call a parent class.

Comment: If `from __future__ import with_statement` actually does anything for you, you're using some crazy-old Python versions - `with` is available by default starting in Python 2.6. The only series where that import is necessary is Python 2.5 - before that, `with` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: What is "parent" and 'child"? Are you executing a subprocess? Using `multiprocessing.Process`? I think platform will matter on this one, are you on a unix-like forking system or a Windows execute system?

Comment: Each module has its own namespace and things needed in it must be imported from other modules/packages (or newly created). This is normal.

Comment: Oh wait, is a "child" just an imported module, in the same process as the parent?

Comment: Generally, a module should have imports for the modules it needs to access directly - and should not import anything it doesn't need to touch. If the module is already imported, it isn't imported again, so no real harm. The import statements document what the module uses. You could have a special module that imports everything and then do something like `from masterimporter import *`, but how many modules is a given module really going to have to import?

Comment: _As an aside, tonight's new class "MsgDisplay" should be in parent and not in child. It was simpler to put the class in the child rather than figuring out how a child could call a parent class._ - you want to avoid circular imports like this. If `foo` imports `bar`, `bar` shouldn't then import `foo`. It sounds like `MsgDisplay` should be in a different module that both import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I must be doing something wrong because a module that is imported should not have > to import what parent already did? In a normal environment the child should know  > inherent what the parent already knows.

You are describing a cpp-like include system where declarations are just placed in order in a single translation unit. That doesn't apply to python. Importing the same module everywhere you use it is necessary. Think about importing as binding the modules contents to the local namespace. If you use module A contents in module B you need to import it in B even if module C already imports A and later B. Don't worry too much about performance. Once a module is loaded by python interpreter remaining imports are not very expensive.